# Fuzzy match and get index of a pattern from a string

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp, fuzzy-search

I have a list of company names that I want to match against a list of sentences and get the index start and end position if a keyword is present in any of the sentences.

I wrote the code for matching the keywords exactly but realized that names in the sentences won't always be an exact match.  For example, my keywords list can contain `Company One Two Ltd` but the sentences can be -

- `Company OneTwo Ltd won the auction`
- `Company One Two Limited won the auction`
- `The auction was won by Co. One Two Ltd`  and other variations

Given a company name, I want to find out the index start and end position even if the company name in the sentence is not an exact match but a variation. Below is the code I wrote for exact matching.

```
def find_index(texts, target):
    idxs = []
    for i, each_sent in enumerate(texts):
        add = [(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(target, each_sent)]
        if len(add):
            idxs.append([(i, m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(target, each_sent)])
    return idxs
```

Comment: you may have to modify the target to be more versatile like `(Company|Co\.?)\s?One\s?Two\s?(Limited|Ltd)`

Comment: @depperm, I have about 10k such company names with not much common in each other for which I am trying to get the indices. This might work for a few cases but it's not going to be possible to go manually through all possibilities.

Comment: while not clean you could iterate through company list and create fuzzy searches `Company`->`(Company|Co\.?)`, `' '`->`\s?`, `Limited`->`(Limited|Ltd)`, etc. It's hard to come up with possible solutions without knowing all the data

Comment: another option is to create a levenshtein distance calculator, though it has its own drawbacks [example](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python)

Comment: @depperm, Levenshtein distance is what I found as well. Looking into it.. Thanks for the link

Comment: @depperm - how about you turn your comments into an answer so that clock-slave can accept?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2-3 possibilities all with varying pros/cons:

1. Create More Versatile regex

`(Company|Co\.?)\s?One\s?Two\s?(Limited|Ltd)`

2. Building on the previous suggestion, iterate through company list and create fuzzy search

`Company->(Company|Co\.?)`, `' '->\s?`, `imited->(Limited|Ltd)`, etc

3. Levenshtein distance calculator

   [example](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python)

which references external library [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/), there are alternatives [fuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/Fuzzy/)